# Cypress Issue is that .type() in is typing given value in reverse direction

Tags: cypress

I used both the {rightarrow} and delay of 5 min to see if the typed value in the input box is correct but it is still giving value in reverse direction

the code line used by me is as below

```
cy.get("input[name='providerName']", { timeout: 60000 }).type('united states{rightarrow}',{delay:5000}).should("have.value", "United States");
```

Please find below the screengrab from the command log

[image]

please feel free to let me know if you need additional details

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with Cypress, but with Chrome.

I copied the answer from this question( https://superuser.com/questions/1216422/chrome-google-search-bar-text-typed-backwards ):

```
Quick fix:

In the address bad, go to 'about://flags'.
Switch 'Force UI Direction' from 'default' to 'Left to Right'.
Running Chrome in Private mode also fixes the issue, which leads me to believe that this is being caused by some extension or setting.
```